# Causal Bayesian network, causal diagram, structural causal model and marginal structural model: what do they exactly mean?

Tags: causality, causal-diagram

In the Book of Why, Judea Pearl gives a comprehensive overview of the *causal diagrams* (or *causal graphs*), but to me, the terminology is not clear yet. In the book, he presents *Bayesian network* in the context of artificial intelligence before introducing the *causal Bayesian network*.

**Question 1**: What is the difference between *causal diagrams* and *causal Bayesian network*?

Additionally, he defines the *structual causal model* (SCM) and justifies its need in order to handle counterfactuals:

> The response function is the key ingredient that gives SCMs the power
> to handle counterfactuals. It is implicit in Rubin’s potential outcome
> paradigm but a major point of difference between SCMs and Bayesian
> networks, including causal Bayesian networks. In a probabilistic
> Bayesian network, the arrows into Y mean that the probability of Y is
> governed by the conditional probability tables for Y, given
> observations of its parent variables. The same is true for causal
> Bayesian networks, except that the conditional probability tables
> specify the probability of Y given interventions on the parent
> variables. Both models specify probabilities for Y, not a specific
> value of Y. In a structural causal model, there are no conditional
> probability tables. The arrows simply mean Y is a function of its
> parents, as well as the exogenous variable $U_Y$:
> $$ Y = f_Y(X, A, B, C,…, U_Y)$$
> (...) To turn a noncausal Bayesian network into a causal model—or, more precisely, to make it capable of answering counterfactual queries—we need a dose-response relationship at each node.

While I understand the need of a model that use a dose-response relationship in order to do counterfactuals, I do not see the difference between the *SCMs*, defined above by Pearl, and the *causal structural model*, defined [in this book](https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2021/01/ciwhatif_hernanrobins_31dec20.pdf), by Hernan and Robins.

**Question 2**: Is there a fundamental difference between these two models?

Comment: Core difference would be vanilla Bayesian networks do not handle interventions out of box. Addition of do-calculus provides one of the ingredient of a causal model, i.e., as Pearl states, making them to answer counterfactual queries. 

 PS: do-operator is the core difference.

Answer (score 7):

I will give my answer based on Pearl's other book ([Causality](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/))

First, some terminology: there are 3 types of queries: observational, interventional, and counterfactual.

- For observational queries, you only need a joint distribution
- For interventional queries, you also need a directed graph (e.g. a Bayesian Network(BN), and especially a Causal Bayesian Network(CBN).) As you quoted, CBNs are required to be able to see how the variables influence each other (hence a graph is used). On a high level, the takeaway should be this simple: you need a graph. The CBN is a BN where you interpret the probabilities in another way.
- For counterfactual queries, you also need to know the quantitative relationship between the different variables. So here you need a graph and a parametrization that describes these functional relationships.

A causal diagram is a [directed acyclic graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)

This provides all we need to answer your first question
**Answer to question 1:**
**TL;DR: SCM = causal diagram + functions for each edge**
The causal diagram is a graph that describes what variables relate to each other, whereas an SCM **additionally gives a quantitative description of these relationships,**

**P.S.:** I cannot find "causal structural models" in the linked book with the search function.
My guess based on Google searches (the term arises in a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220487167_Causes_and_Explanations_A_Structural-Model_Approach_Part_I_Causes) co-authored by Pearl) that they are the same